# Verilog Return X for Every Test Case In Generate Syntax for Barrel Shifter

Tags: verilog, hdl

In Wrote A module for 8 bit barrel shifter and rotate, and it return x for outputs, i don't know how to solve it !
I should write this module with generate syntax, i uploaded picture for 4 bit barrel shifter and rotate

[image: modeling]

```
module OneGate(input D, S, W0, output W);
    wire Temp;
    and (Temp, D, S);
    or (W, Temp, W0);
endmodule

module Barrel_Shifter_8_bit(input [7:0]D, [7:0]S, SbarR, output [8:0]W);
    integer i;
    wire Temp;
    wire [8:0]WW[8:0];
    genvar col, row;
    generate
        for (row = 0; row < 8; row = row + 1) begin
            for (col = 0; col < 8; col = col + 1) begin
                if (col == 0) begin
                    assign WW[row][0] = 0;
                end
                if (row + col < 8)
                    OneGate Gates(D[row + col], S[col], WW[row][col], WW[row][col+1]);
                else
                    OneGate Gates(D[col - ( 3 - row)] & SbarR, S[col], WW[row][col], WW[row][col+1]);
            end
        end
    endgenerate
    assign W = '{WW[0][7], WW[1][7], WW[2][7], WW[3][7], WW[4][7], WW[5][7], WW[6][7], WW[7][7], WW[8][7]};
endmodule

module Test;
    reg [7:0]In = '{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    reg [7:0]Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
    wire [8:0]W = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    Barrel_Shifter_8_bit TempB(In, Se, 0, W);
    initial begin
        #10;
        #50 Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
        #50 Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
        #50 Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        #50 Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
        #50;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have multiple drivers on `W` in your testbench. Change `wire [8:0]W = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` to `wire [8:0] W;` and you will see 1s where there where Xs.

---

Other notes:

- `'{}` as assigning a packed array is very uncommon. I recommend changes to a more standard format. Example: `Se = '{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};` to `Se = 8'b0000_1000;` or `Se = 8'h8;`
- `input [7:0]D, [7:0]S, SbarR, output [8:0]W` infers `SbarR` as `[7:0] SbarR`. Recommend changing to `input [7:0] D, S, input SbarR, output [7:0] W`
- `W[8]`, `WW[8]`, and `WW[*][8]` are never used, make them 8-bit wide instead of 9-bits. `wire [7:0] W;`, `wire [7:0] WW [7:0];`